# Are SpriteKit Scene (.sks) files necessary in my project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I tried searching and couldn't find the answer. Is it necessary to have a matching .sks file for each of my scene files? If I delete my matching .sks files will there be a problem? I understand this file is kind of for interface building but I haven't utilized them at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need them. You can create all your `SKScene` content directly in Swift code.

Just keep in mind that Xcode 8 support for SpriteKit Scenes is pretty nice, providing a nice game design/production workflow. In particular, you can create `*.sks` files with simple, *reusable* nodes (e.g., crates, monsters, coins, etc) and use them across your game.

Having said that, please double check your `*.sks` files are actually empty before deleting them all ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No, but if you don't want to use them, you will have to change the way that your `GameViewController.swift` file instantiates your scene - instead of:

```
let scene = SKSCene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

you will have to use

```
let scene = SKSCene(size: CGSize)
```